# How to remove thumbs from part page and bibliography?

Tags: fancyhdr, chapterthumb

I would like to use `thumbs` but not on the part pages and on the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
    \ChNameVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChNumVar{\Huge\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChTitleVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\scshape\color{black}}

\usepackage[height={2cm},distance={5mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\thumbforchapter}{\addthumb{Chapter \thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{Test 1}
\chapter{Intro} \label{chap:1}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-15]\cite{happel}

\part{Test 2}
\chapter{Mid} \label{chap:2}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-9]\cite{happel}

\chapter{End} \label{chap:3}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[15-19]\cite{happel}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{happel} 
Patrick Happel.
lipsum -- Easy access to the Lorem Ipsum dummy text.
2014
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

How do I restrict `thumbs`? Is it better to use `fancyhdr`?

Also, in my real code, the thumbs do not really shift downwards before the fifth chapter. I was however unable to recreate it here in this MWE.

Comment: Put `\clearpage \stopthumb` before the `\part` and the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you, @Pieter van Oostrum. Your comment solved the issue. :)

Comment: @PietervanOostrum: please add an answer so that it can be clear in the search that there is a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put \clearpage \stopthumb before the \part and the bibliography.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
    \ChNameVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChNumVar{\Huge\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChTitleVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\scshape\color{black}}

\usepackage[height={2cm},distance={5mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\thumbforchapter}{\addthumb{Chapter \thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpage \stopthumb
\part{Test 1}
\chapter{Intro} \label{chap:1}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-15]\cite{happel}

\clearpage \stopthumb
\part{Test 2}
\chapter{Mid} \label{chap:2}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-9]\cite{happel}

\chapter{End} \label{chap:3}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[15-19]\cite{happel}

\clearpage \stopthumb
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{happel} 
Patrick Happel.
lipsum -- Easy access to the Lorem Ipsum dummy text.
2014
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

As a proof, see the Bibliography page.

[image]