# How to avoid refsection from interrupting the position of thumbs?

Tags: biblatex, chapterthumb

I asked a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588460/how-to-remove-thumbs-from-part-page-and-bibliography?noredirect=1#comment1478288_588460) yesterday in which asked how to remove `thumbs` from parts and bibliography. @Pieter van Oostrum commented with the solution which is to put `\clearpage` `\stopthumb` before `\part` and `\printbibliography`. However, I also mentioned that the thumbs did not shift down properly, which I found out later is caused by `refsection` in some of the chapter (I am writing a collection of manuscripts so I need individual bibliographies in addition to the main bibliography at the end). The MWE's `main.tex` is:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
    \ChNameVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChNumVar{\Huge\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChTitleVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\scshape\color{black}}

\usepackage[height={2cm},distance={5mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\newcommand{\thumbforchapter}{\addthumb{Chapter \thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{Introduction}

\chapter{Intro} \label{chap:1}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-5] \cite{lipsum}
\clearpage \stopthumb

\part{Manuscripts}

\begin{refsection}

\chapter{Manuscript $1$} \label{chap:2}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[6-10] \cite{lipsum}

\printbibliography[title={BIBLIOGRAPHY},heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}

\chapter{Manuscript 2} \label{chap:3}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[11-15] \cite{lipsum}

\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}

\chapter{Manuscript 3} \label{chap:4}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[16-20] \cite{lipsum}
\clearpage \stopthumb

\end{refsection}

\part{Conclusion}

\chapter{Conclusion} \label{chap:5}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[21]

\clearpage \stopthumb

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The MWE's `bibliography.bib` is:

```
@Manual{lipsum,
    title = {lipsum -- Easy access to the Lorem Ipsum dummy text},
    author = {Patrick Happel},
    year = {2014},
    note = {\LaTeX~package version 1.3},
    url = {https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum},
}
```

How do I prevent `refsection` from interrupting with the `thumbs`?

Also, is it possible to remove `thumbs` from the chapter page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An environment like `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` implies a group, which means that everything that happens inside that group is local to the group unless it is specifically declared global.

In particular the position calculations of `\addthumb` are done via local assignments, so the position does not take the `\thumbforchapter` inside `refsection`s into account.

One way to resolve this would be to make `thumb` use global counter operations everywhere (almost all of its other operations are already global). (That said, it is generally quite unusual to have grouping across large parts of the document, so I can imagine that the `thumb` package author did not want to account for that.)

Unfortunately, the required code changes would be fairly far-reaching (an earlier version of the answer contained a fix that only worked for in some situations, a real solution would have to be much more comprehensive).

Another solution that works in the MWE (because there are no citations in the chapter headings) is to move the `\thumbforchapter` outside the `refsection`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
    \ChNameVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChNumVar{\Huge\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\color{black}}
    \ChTitleVar{\Large\fontfamily{cmbright}\selectfont\scshape\color{black}}
\usepackage[height={2cm},distance={5mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand{\thumbforchapter}{\addthumb{Chapter \thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{Introduction}

\chapter{Intro} \label{chap:1}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-5] \cite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage \stopthumb

\part{Manuscripts}

\chapter{Manuscript $1$} \label{chap:2}\thumbforchapter
\begin{refsection}
\lipsum[6-10] \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[title={BIBLIOGRAPHY},heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\chapter{Manuscript 2} \label{chap:3}\thumbforchapter
\begin{refsection}
\lipsum[11-15] \cite{sigfridsson}
\end{refsection}

\chapter{Manuscript 3} \label{chap:4}\thumbforchapter
\begin{refsection}
\lipsum[16-20] \cite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage \stopthumb
\end{refsection}

\part{Conclusion}

\chapter{Conclusion} \label{chap:5}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[21]

\clearpage \stopthumb

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow -- thank you, @moewe. I am really impressed by our answer. There are however a few flaws with the first alternative: thumbs on pages 4, 8, and 10 are out of position. The second alternative works as charm though. :)

Comment: @naughty_waves Oh yeah. Sorry, I didn't notice that. I had another look at `thumb` and found quite a number of other local assignments that have to be made global. I removed the half-working fix.

Comment: Thank you again, @moewe. I am grateful for your help. :)